# Is a Digital Subscriber Line (DSL) connection a phone call by legal definition?

Tags: hacking, harassment, communications-law

Is a Digital Subscriber Line (DSL) considered a phone call by legal definition? As such, could I use state laws such as Washington State [RCW 9.61](https://app.leg.wa.gov/RCW/default.aspx?cite=9.61), for instance, to pursue civil action against someone who say disrupts, convludes, degrades, or otherwise attacks my home network connection over DSL as harassment?

I attempted to skim an [article on HowStuffWorks.com](https://computer.howstuffworks.com/dsl.htm) related to DSL, but there only seems to be a vauge implication that there is some kind of initial connection (a phone call?) which is then maintained throughout the life of the subscription, but does not seem to have anything that leads me to a definative conclusion about the nature of a DSL connection being a phone call.

Comment: Why does it matter? Do you have a law in mind that says “phone call” rather than “telecommunication”? Such laws would be very rare today.

Comment: The law referenced in my question uses the wording "shall make a telephone call to" in reference to determining an offense of harassment.

Comment: What is "convludes"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> could I use state laws such as Washington State RCW 9.61, for instance, to pursue civil action against someone who say disrupts, convludes, degrades, or otherwise attacks my home network connection over DSL

RCW 9.61 concerns only "making a telephone call," not disrupting, convluding(?), degrading, or otherwise attacking anything.  In a DSL connection, the only person establishing the connection ("making" the "call") is the DSL subscriber.  A closer analogy to telephone communication would be somehow impeding a victim's ability to make a telephone call.

Furthermore, to be covered, a telephone call must disturb the recipient in some way that engages item (a), (b), or (c).  DSL is designed to allow normal telephone communication to continue while the DSL connection is underway: a DSL subscriber can make and receive telephone calls normally.  It's difficult to see how a malicious actor could disrupt a target's internet connection by making a call.  If it were somehow possible, the phone calls might incidentally trigger this statute (for example if they are repeated -- see item (b)), but the attack itself on the target's internet connection would probably have to be prosecuted under laws criminalizing interference with telecommunications more generally.

While it's certainly possible that there are circumstances under which a DSL connection might be considered a telephone call, it's hard to imagine how they could apply to RCW 9.61.  If they could, the statute would cover a malicious actor establishing a DSL connection to a victim (for one of the purposes outlined in (a), (b), or (c)), and that's not even possible.

If you're asking whether this law could be involved because the person who's attacking your network is a DSL subscriber rather than having, say, a fiber optic connection, then I still doubt it.  Even if establishing a DSL connection can be said to be making a phone call, the recipient of the call in this case is the telecommunication company as an internet service provider, whereas the statute only covers phone calls made "to such other person" -- to the victim of the harassment.

Comment: Highly inciteful, same page about the ISP conn., but I was aiming more at the idea of a DSL connection being classified as a telephone call. Such that is uses the same infrastructure and method (analog as opposed to digital) over that medium. Further the interuption of the components that serve as the primary infrastructure for connection are also dependancies of a DSL connection. (e.g. cutting a phone line also cuts the DSL line.) This is to avoid an alternate of classification of HTTP requests to some IP might be "like a" telephone call in such a way the same wording and laws could be used.

Comment: @Chezzwizz the problem here, then, is that the example turns not on the definition of "phone call" but on the definition of "makes," "to," and "harass."  If I have a DSL connection and I use it to send harassing e-mail messages, have I "made" a "phone call" "to" the recipient?  To me it is clear that the answer is "no," though I wouldn't be surprised if some judge disagrees.  But the acts that are covered by the statute all require the victim to be aware of the harassment: they're disturbed by the phone ringing or by the communication. Degrading your network just doesn't qualify.

Comment: Thank you for that. Super inciteful! As a political aside for record, I ask this question with a bias from the other side of the fence and hope that such transactions over the digital network can in fact be classified the same way as phone calls so we can better regulate them on close to a century of groundwork layed out by institutions like the FCC. Why is it still the wild west I ask...